# How to enable or disable a button inside Gridview based on condition in Inline Eval DateTime Value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, datetime, eval

I am trying to enable or disable a LinkButton inside ItemTemplate of Gridview based on DateTime value.
I want to ensure that if the DateTime column of Gridview is less than 30mins then LinkButton should be disabled and once the DateTime column is past 30 minutes then LinkButton should get enabled.

```html
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvAt" ShowHeader="false" OnRowDataBound="gvAt_RowDataBound" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk" /> 
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="linkAt" text="" /></ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("CreatorName")%></map></ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("CreatedDate")%></ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate><asp:LinkButton  runat="server" ID="btnDelete" text="Delete" OnClick="btnDelete_Clicked" Enabled='<%# (DateTime)Eval("CreatedDate") < DateTime.Now ? false : true %>' /> </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            
        </asp:GridView>
```

**Eval("CreatedDate")** is a date time field which I want to compare with Current Date and Time. Currently I am comparing it with **DateTime.Now** but I want to know how to check If Current DateTime is not more than 30mins from Created DateTime and then Link Button **btnDelete** should not be visible and it should get visible only when it is more than 30mins.
Any help would be highly useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:LinkButton  runat="server" ID="btnDelete" text="Delete" OnClick="btnDelete_Clicked" Enabled='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("CreatedDate")) > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30) ?  true : false  %>' />
```

You must probably asked how to add/subtract minutes on datetime, So it could be done by AddMinutes i.e DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30).

Comment: It's usually a good idea to explain your answer instead of just dumping code. Let the OP know what you did to fix it

Comment: @dilli: Thanks for your response but it won't work since DateTime.now is not evaluated inside Enable Property like this. Any other suggestion please?

Comment: I don't know if you have some other issue, otherwise this code should work just fine and I have used it many times. There should be no problem using any expression inside Enabled or Visible which finally return boolean value. More over, you even can create function "public .." in code behind with parameter and pass the date value, and return the boolean. i.e Visible='<%# YourFunciton(parm) %>'